# Finding maximum or minimum date value for each individual

Tags: r, date, formatting

I have a `dataframe` in a wide format in R, denoting different visit dates for each individual (`visitdate1, visitdate2, visitdate3`, etc.). I'm trying to find the latest date for each individual and save it as a new column, but this doesn't seem to be working.

I checked the class of the `dataframe` and each `visitdate` is already recognized as a Date, so I don't know why the code is not working.

This is the code I tried:

```
df1$latestdate <- pmax(as_date(df1$visitdate1), as_date(df1$visitdate2), 
as_date(df1$visitdate3))
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
>     do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”

The problem is that I'm asking R to find the maximum date value per row, not to convert any date (as it's already a date). 
However, even when I leave `as_date` out of the code, I get the error that :

> replacement has 0 rows, data has 120.

Any insight that might help? Thanks in advance! Btw, I'm new to R. :)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Below I provide an example, kind of guessing what your data looks like. pmax may not be the best thing for this.

```
DATES = seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2017-01-01'),"months") 

df = data.frame(id=1:10,
visitdate1 = sample(DATES,10),
visitdate2 = sample(DATES,10),
visitdate3 = sample(DATES,10)
)
#set columns to find row Max
COLUMNS = c("visitdate1","visitdate2","visitdate3")
df$latestdate = apply(df[,COLUMNS],1,max)
```